# Why does an aggregate query perform a sort?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have three tables that will be joined with sum/count data in the third table. Here's the query:

```
SELECT a.company_id,
    c.asal_id,
    c.tujuan_id,
    c.barang_id,
    sum(c.berat) AS berat,
    count(c.berat) AS qty,
    b.pack_date,
    c.owner_id
   FROM tbl_scanning a
     LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction b ON a.id = b.scann_id
     LEFT JOIN tbl_stock c ON b.id = c.transaction_id
  GROUP BY a.company_id, b.pack_date, c.asal_id, c.tujuan_id, c.barang_id, c.owner_id
  ORDER BY a.company_id;
```

The result of explain analyze shows this query does a sort for the six fields in the `GROUP BY` clause, which makes the query very slow. How to avoid the sort? Or what else can I do to make my query run faster?

What I already do:

1. Make index (company_id) in table a, (pack_date) in table b and (asal_id, tujuan_id, barang_id, owner_id) in table c
2. Set `work_mem` to 900MB (already using quick sort memory)

My explain analyze [is here](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/77478efe501e57cc).

[image: Explain analyze]

Comment: What happens if you drop the ORDER BY?

Comment: Those three index scans, none with index conditions, are very weird.  Have you played around with enable_seqscan and other such parameters before gather this plan?

Comment: In addition to the above two good hints: PostgreSQL is more likely to use a hash aggregate from v13 on (but probably only without the `ORDER BY`).